# How can I adjust the threshold while implementing logistic regression using Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

While performing binary classification using Scikit-learn, suppose I want to set the threshold to a particular value, say 0.75, how can it be done?

Comment: It would be useful if you had an example to go off of

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can however use `predict_proba` which returns an array with the probabilities per class. You can then select based on your own threshold.